# How to get rid of HTML-tags in a message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

For the last time I've been using EWS MAPI to connect to Exchange Server. After this is done I access my mails and firstly display their body (which contains a LOT HTML-tags) in a gridview. After you select a record of that gridview the body is shown in a freetextbox.

My problem is that I want to get rid of the HTML in the body. And configure the freetextbox so that it still displays the the text in his true format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the grid you want text only (ie remove the HTML) and in the FreeTextBox HTML Editor you want the original formatted string, right?

Comment: that's what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

have a look at: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Comment: This is what I do but it doesn't work
string regex = "(\\<.*\\])|(\".*\")|('.*')|(\\(.*\\))";

string output = Regex.Replace(Request.QueryString["omschrijving"], regex, "");

Comment: I added a similar thread to the post. take a look at it, may be it'll help

Comment: @Massimo How/where are you using the `output` variable?

Comment: at the moment i'm using it in a dummytextbox just for testing

Comment: The link I gave includes suggestions about Html Agility Pack, you better look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse Html and strip out what you want. There are a lot of information on SO about it, for example: [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Comment: Just noting here (as required per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156184) that the library Simon is recommending is one that he is the author of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

[Convert special chars to HTML entities, without changing tags and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891134/convert-special-chars-to-html-entities-without-changing-tags-and-parameters)

Comment: do you know how to delete all the text between < and > ?

Comment: You can do this with a regular expression. But is this really what you want? Don't you want to convert the <br> and <p> to newline characters, the <b> to bold text, etc?

Comment: that's the job of the freetextbox, but I have to configure it so that it can convert HTML. in the gridview I don't want to see any html. I'm asking you because I never used regex

Comment: @Massimo You can do something like `Regex.Replace(string, "\<.*\>", "")`. This looks for all places where `<` is followed by any string and then followed by `>`, and replaces them with `""`.

Comment: that's exactly what i do but it doesn't work. is it because I'm applying it on a Request.QueryString ???

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with encoding. Maybe you have `&lt;` instead of `<` or something like that.

Comment: no, that's not true. Regex really does nothing because if i run this code: 
input contains: "geeeeekdldn"
Regex.Replace(input, @"g(.|\n)*?n", string.Empty);
 
normally after regex the value of input is "" but i get "geeeeekdldn"
any help please

Comment: @Massimo so ask this as a new question. Your question was too broad, that's why you didn't get a specific answer.